# Why does notifyAll() raise IllegalMonitorStateException when synchronized on Integer?

Tags: java, synchronization, notify, illegalmonitorstateexcep

Why does this test program result in a `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`?

```
public class test {
    static Integer foo = new Integer(1);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        synchronized(foo) {
            foo++;
            foo.notifyAll();
        }
        System.err.println("Success");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
        at test.main(test.java:6)
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You have noted correctly that `notifyAll` must be called from a synchronized block.

However, in your case, because of auto-boxing, the object you synchronized on is not the same instance that you invoked `notifyAll` on. In fact, the new, incremented `foo` instance is still confined to the stack, and no other threads could possibly be blocked on a `wait` call.

You could implement your own, mutable counter on which synchronization is performed. Depending on your application, you might also find that [AtomicInteger](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) meets your needs.

Comment: I failed to realize that incrementing the Integer would allocate a new object instead of changing the value of the existing object.

Comment: Trying to wait/notify using an Enum can also lead to this condition: `synchronized (myEnum) { myEnum=MyEnum.NEW_VALUE; myEnum.notify(); }`

Comment: For those looking for a solution to a boolean, use AtomicBoolean as the wrapper type

Comment: @dmitrii, yes indeed, but here you are explicitly modifying the reference. That applies to ANY object reference, not only enums.

Comment: It's very tempting to use a primitive type wrapper both as the synchronizer and the condition data. What a mistake!

Answer (score 3):

You should also be leery of locking or notifying on objects like String and Integer that can be interned by the JVM (to prevent creating a lot of objects that represent the integer 1 or the string "").

Answer (score 3):

Incrementing the Integer makes the old foo disappear and be replaced with a brand new object foo which is not synchronized with the previous foo variable.

Here is an implementation of AtomicInteger that erickson suggested above.  In this example foo.notifyAll(); does not produce a java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException beause the AtomicInteger Object is not refreshed when foo.incrementAndGet(); is run.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class SynchronizeOnAPrimitive {
    static AtomicInteger foo = new AtomicInteger(1);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        synchronized (foo) {
            foo.incrementAndGet();
            foo.notifyAll();
        }
        System.out.println("foo is: " + foo);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
foo is: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

As erickson has noted, the code without the postincrement operator works without error:

```
static Integer foo = new Integer(1);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    synchronized (foo) {
        foo.notifyAll();
    }
    System.out.println("Success");
}
```

output:

> Success