# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException on notifyAll() method

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, illegalmonitorstateexcep

I am still learning on Threads following java tutorials of oracle website.

With regarding to the wait() and notifyAll(), I have written some code. My expected output is print the message in run() 10 times and print the "Fun stopped by StopFun Thread" message in `guardedJoy(GuardedBlock guardedBlock)` method when the 'joy' set to false in the run method.

This is my code.

```
public class GuardedBlock {

private boolean joy = true;

public synchronized void guardedJoy(GuardedBlock guardedBlock) {

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Guard Joy method started");
    while (guardedBlock.joy) {
        try {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Going to waiting state");
            guardedBlock.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Fun stopped by StopFun Thread");
}

private static class StopFun implements Runnable {

    private GuardedBlock guardedBlock;

    public StopFun(GuardedBlock guardedBlock) {
        this.guardedBlock = guardedBlock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.println("Allowing fun since its only " + x + " times - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                if (x == 10) {
                    guardedBlock.joy = false;
                    guardedBlock.notifyAll();
                    break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GuardedBlock guardedBlock = new GuardedBlock();

    StopFun sf = new StopFun(guardedBlock);
    Thread stopFun = new Thread(sf);
    stopFun.start();

    guardedBlock.guardedJoy(guardedBlock);
    }
}
```

The code in the run method runs fine but afterwards it throws an exception like this.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at Synchronization.GuardedBlock$StopFun.run(GuardedBlock.java:38)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I went through couple of questions and answers in the site like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260337/why-does-notifyall-raise-illegalmonitorstateexception-when-synchronized-on-int/%22this%22) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209552/notifyall-throws-illegalmonitorstateexception) but could not figure out what exactly I am doing wrong. A help is much valued.

Thanks.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll--) is your friend:  “**Throws:** IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of this object's monitor.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wait()` and `notify()`/`notifyAll()` must be called in a `synchronized` block.

```
synchronized (guardedBlock) {
    guardedBlock.notifyAll();
}
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question though.wait() is already in a synchronized method. So do I need to introduce a separate synchronized block?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that the method is synchronized. But it is synchronized on `this`, and `wait()` is called on `guardedBlock`. In your program is so happens that `guardedBlock` matches `this` at the moment of the call due to `guardedBlock.guardedJoy(guardedBlock);`, and it should work without an additional `synchronized` block, but this is a bit fragile. And of course, `notifyAll()` must be under synchronization as well.

Comment: It's better to place `guardedBlock.joy = false;` in synchronized block as well.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the clarification :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out because I'm using your code and placed the call to notifyAll() in a synchronized method and still receive the error...